# Google Cloud Serverless VPC Connector not working for App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to set up a project with an App Engine service that talks to a Cloud SQL database with Private IP connectivity. This is achievable through the [Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) of Google Cloud, that allows App Engine and Cloud Functions to interact with resources in your private VPC.

For some unexplicable reason, I was able to interrogate the DB from a test Cloud Function, but *not* from App Engine, where I get a connection refused error. Since it works on Cloud Functions, it makes me think that the Serverless VPC Access is properly configured, but I still can't understand why it doesn't work with App Engine.

The App Engine app is deployed using `gcloud app deploy`. I also tried `gcloud beta app deploy` as somebody suggested but nothing changed.
Everything (App Engine, Cloud Function, Cloud SQL) is in the same region, `europe-west1`. I am not using the gcloud default network but a custom network, with a single subnetwork in the same region.

If you have any remote idea on what could possibly be misconfigured, please let me know as I really am losing hope on this. Thanks!

Comment: Is your VPC serverless access is also in europe-west1? What type of database do you try to reach? Do you use the database private IP for function and AppEngine, or do you use App Engine embedded database connexion (that you define in your app.yaml file)?

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere. In the end I discovered that everything was configured properly, there was just some sneaky configuration problem in my code.
To answer your questions: I was trying to reach a Cloud SQL database configured with private IP connectivity only. Everything is in the same region